How can i export Events from Bugsnag?
I am new to this but I have logged into BugSnag and I can see my Events (Errors).
How can i export these events to a excel file and can i call a Bugsnag api that can export all of these ?
I have tried to look at Bugsnag documentation but havent had any luck yet.
Any help would be appreciated .
Im expecting a Excel file that has all these Events / Errors .
I have tried this:
$apiKey = <API_KEY>
$apiUrl = "https://api.bugsnag.com/errors"
$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $apiKey"
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers - 
 Method Get

$response
But it gives an error "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
How do i know what the page is for errors ?
